# have been working or worked?

Tags: past-simple, present-perfect-progressive

It is 10 o'clock in the evening and I am tired because I had a busy day at work. (I finished work at 6 o'clock.) Can I say

> I'm tired because I've been working hard all day

or do I have to say

> I'm tired because I worked hard all day

because the working stopped a few hours ago?

Comment: We have dealt with this before: It depends on what you want to say. The first one  means the day is not yet finished. The second implies it is finished for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, your examples have the same meaning given your situation.

Comment: I thought that maybe the present perfect continuous could only be used if the work had just finished.

Comment: Can I say I'm tired because I've been working hard all morning when it is afternoon? Or is that different?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine.